# How to float right but align left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm typesetting a formal letter within a much larger document (hundreds of pages). I'd like to produce something along the lines of what you get with the `letter` document class, but without actually that class. (I'm heavily invested in `memoir` already.)

The main thing I'm struggling with is the address. The requirement is that the address box float all the way right, but be left-aligned within the box.

The best I've achieved is this hack:

```
\hspace*{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
Joe Bloggs\\
123 ABC Street\\
Townville, Regionia\\
Countrystan\\
Friday, May 29, 2015
\end{minipage}
```

but the results are unsatisfactory.

How do I float this address right but have it aligned flush left?

Comment: To add an image in your post, see [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764) You'll find the Meta for this site by clicking on the Stack Exchange menu, and selecting [meta.tex.se].

Answer (score 4):

Put the address inside a `tabular` and use `\hfill` to shove it over to the right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Joe Bloggs \\
  123 ABC Street \\
  Townville, Regionia \\
  Countrystan \\
  Friday, May 29, 2015
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The column gap was removed on the right of the `l`eft-aligned column using `@{}`. There's no need to remove it on the left as the content is filled from the left margin anyway.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've used your code from this solution only to compare the outputs of two methods in a single image. I am still new on TeX.SX and don't know if I should've asked for your permission to use your code before posting my answer. Hope that's fine with you.

Answer (score 1):

This method is based on `\parbox[pos][height][contentpos]{width}{text}`. A new length variable `\lnglen` is declared and its value is set to the width of the longest line in your input text (which is the last line showing date) using `\settowidth` macro. Now, we can use this length variable to set the width of `\parbox` in order to make it exactly as wide as the input text, so that it won't leave any trailing space when flushed to right edge using `\hfill`.

To show you the exact width of the output, I've added a `\vrule` at the left edge of `parbox` and just for the sake of better comparison, I've included @werner's solution at the top with a `vrule` as well.

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe} % Just for this example
\newlength{\lnglen} % defines a new custom length variable
\settowidth{\lnglen}{Friday, May 29, 2015} % sets variable value to longest line's width
\begin{document}
%
%%%%%% by @werner %%%%%%
\hfill
\vrule               % added by @amar
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Joe Bloggs \\
  123 ABC Street \\
  Townville, Regionia \\
  Countrystan \\
  Friday, May 29, 2015
\end{tabular}
%%%%%% by @werner %%%%%%
%
\vspace*{0.2in}
\hrule
\vspace*{0.2in}
%
%%%%%% by @amar %%%%%%
\hfill % flushes everything to right
\vrule
\parbox[c][][s]{\lnglen}{% sets \parbox of \lnglen width!
  Joe Bloggs \\
  123 ABC Street \\
  Townville, Regionia \\
  Countrystan \\
  Friday, May 29, 2015
}%
%%%%%% by @amar %%%%%%
%
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]